# detectar si la web esta funcionando en chrome app o en electron

Tags: javascript, electron

hola estoy creando una web que mostrara diferente contenido en navegador y en la app de electron

me tope con este codigo `(process.versions.electron != 'undefined' && process.versions.electron != null)` pero este en navegador y en electron no funciona lo que intento ocultar es un boton con la id de `biblioteca`

```
if(process.versions.electron != 'undefined' && process.versions.electron != null){
    document.getElementById("biblioteca").style.display = "block";
}else{
    document.getElementById("biblioteca").style.display = "none";
}
```

```
boton en mi index.html
<button id="biblioteca">Biblioteca</button>
```

para ser mas espesifico lo que busco crear es que la web detecte si esta en un navegador comun ej opera,firefox,chrome etx o directamente en el navegador de electron js

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el atributo `webPreferences.preload` en las opciones al llamar a [`BrowserWindow( )`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions).

Esto te permite cargar *scripts* locales **antes de cualquier otro script de la página**, pero usando el mismo DOM.

La idea es usarlo para crear una *marca* que te permita distinguir si estás en `electron` o en un navegador *normal*:

Por ejemplo, supongamos un proyecto mínimo en `electron`:

> /
>      package.json
>      index.js
>      preload.js

El archivo `preload.js` es bastante simple:

```
window['ThisPageIsRunningInElectron'] = 'UnTextoRaroQueSeaDifícilEncontrarEnPáginasNormales' ;
```

Y en tu archivo principal `index.js`, en donde creas la ventana del navegador, haces:

```
MainWindow = new ElectronModule.BrowserWindow( {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  title: 'Concept Test',
  webPreferences: {
    webSecurity: false,
    preload: PathModule.join( __dirname, '/preload.js' ),
    nodeIntegration: false,
    allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'UTF-8',
  }
} );
```

Como ves, **deshabilitamos** la integración de `node` con la página, para garantizar máxima compatibilidad, e indicamos el archivo `preload` a cargar.

Ahora, una vez cargado tu URL, desde dentro de tu página `.html`, puedes comprobar facilmente si estás o no en `electron`:

```
if( window['ThisPageIsRunningInElectron'] === 'UnTextoRaroQueSeaDifícilEncontrarEnPáginasNormales' ) {
  // Este código se ejecutará solo si estamos en electron.
}
```

Por supuesto, tu archivo `preload.js` puede ser **todo lo complejo que quieras**. Piensa que ese archivo es tratado por electron como si hicieras

```
<script src="file:///preload.js"></script>
```

por lo que puedes meter todo el código que necesites, incluido cargar otras URL (pero recuerda que esos *scripts* así cargados **solo estará disponibles** en `electron`).

Comment: funciona con ``loadURL("http://localhost/");``? por que la app cargará una URL no un archivo html local

Comment: @Max La verdad es que no lo se. Hace mas de 1 año que hice esta prueba. Según la doc, solo sirve para archivos locales. Pero piensa que cuanto mas cosas metas ahí, mas distinta será tu página de una página normal.

Answer (score 0):

Tu estas compilando tu propia solución. El código de electron, y el de chrome a pesar de ser parecidos, podrían contener diferencias. En tu ejemplo, el navegador no tiene acceso al process. Mientras que un entorno en nodejs si podría tenerlo. Por otro lado, hay formas de detectar que el script se ejecuta en node. Mediante la comprobación del process:

(process === undefined) && (process.release.name === 'node')

Sin embargo, debe tener en cuenta que eso no signifique que su script se esté ejecutando en electron.js

Ya que usted compila su propia solución podría agregar banderas a las distintas builds de producción. Algo tan simple como process.targetEnv = "electron" y comprobarlo al comienzo podría funcionar.